# Make AudioBufferSourceNode the audio source of an <audio> tag?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

One direction of this exchange is possible - I know you can use the source of an `<audio>` element as a means of getting audio for use with the Web Audio API via `createElementSourceNode()`. Is it possible to do the opposite, where an `AudioBufferSourceNode` is used as the source for an `<audio>` element?

I'm pretty sure this is impossible, but I've been looking through npm for standard-looking, no-frills recreations of default browser audio element playback controls intended for use with `AudioBuffers` and I'm not finding anything.

Comment: You mean in node.js? web-audio-api is intended for browsers so are HTMLAudioElements.

Comment: Sorry - I'm using node.js with babel to bundle everything, probably should get rid of that tag. This is all happening on the browser.

Comment: Why do you need this? After all, if you have an AudioBufferSourceNode, you have an AudioContext, and you can plug the node into the AudioContext's output and get sound out.

Comment: Most of the time I'm just playing segments of a large audiosprited file, but if the user wants to view more info for an object, I want to give them the ability to play just that object's audio, with standard audio controls. I'd mute everything else in the background. I don't *need* it to be in an `<audio>` tag, I'm just having a hard time finding a library that emulates those controls outside of the `<audio>` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect your AudioBufferSourceNode to a [MediaStreamDestination node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode) and then feed an [HTMLAudioElement `srcObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject) with the [`.stream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode/stream) property of this node:

```js
start.onclick = e => {

  const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  fetch("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3")
  .then(resp => resp.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buf => audioCtx.decodeAudioData(buf))
  .then(audioBuffer => {
    const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.playbackRate.value = 0.1;
    source.loop = true;
    source.start(0);
    const streamNode = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
    source.connect(streamNode);
    const audioElem = new Audio();
    audioElem.controls = true;
    document.body.appendChild(audioElem);
    audioElem.srcObject = streamNode.stream;
  })
  .catch(console.error);
}
```

```html
<button id="start">start</button>
```

Comment: Interesting that this seems to keep adding time onto the playbar as it loops, rather than jumping the playhead back to the beginning when it restarts?

Comment: That's because it's a MediaStream that is being played. This MediaStream is itself fed by the looping AudioBufferSource

Comment: @Kaiido sorry for the late reply - I'm a bit of a novice with this stuff - if I set loop to false, how can I make the audio element stop at the end of the joined buffer?